# Regular Expression - Extract Words and number

Tags: regex, google-sheets, expression, formula

So I'm using Regexextract in GoogleSheet to find the value for a big amount of data. I have 2 problems I don't know to extract or what I did wrong. Feel free to point out my mistakes and help me with a solution.
Require: I need to extract the part number which format is ABCD#### or ABCD-#### which is is Upper character and numbers follow after, with or w/o "-" , for example KTA1763 or SPD-4124
@ I use this formula: =Regexextract(A1,"([A-Z]+-?[0-9]*)") .FYI, the values I'm extracting, it could appear either at the beginning, middle or last.

1.First problem, I have the value as below:
REACH TECH 223/224 list document for KTD2026BEWE-TR
=> Extract result : REACH
[What I need: KTD2026]

2.I have the value as:
information for Part number KTA1550EDS-TR
=> Extract result: P
[What I need: KTA1550]

Please let me know which part in the formula should I fix to have the final expected result. Or how should I alter my formula for that matter, big thanks

Comment: Maybe replace asterisk with plus? `=Regexextract(A1,"([A-Z]+-?[0-9]+)")`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**  *in one cell*.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, ".+"&REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "[0-9]+")), ".+\s(.+)")))
```

[image]

Comment: This method is not correct, if your input includes Upper case letter like DBFSB, the output will come out totally different. I just tried. Thanks for your comment though

Comment: The sure thing in the data is 4 number after letter without space ?

Comment: its fixed now give it a try

Comment: It could be 1 or many number. I got this fixed now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

go for:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "[A-Z]+\d+")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I just found out that why I don't use \d instead [0-9], which did fix it!